# Filter ListView when tab changed

Tags: android, listview, filter, tabs

I need to filter a ListView in one activity with three tabs. For instance, I have one tab where are displayed info about all the devices (custom object), but when I change to other tab, it should display the devices of "type1" and when I change to the last tab it displays the devices of "type2".

I already have a custom adapter, and I want to know if I can use the Filterable interface (... implements Filterable ...) and override the getFilter() method (like filtering based on editText) or I should use another approach?

Grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this using the `onTabChanged()` method, like this (in the `onCreate()`):

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Log.d(debugTag, "onTabChanged: tab number=" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());

            switch (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
            case 0:
                myDevAdapter.getFilter().filter("all");
                break;
            case 1:
                myDevAdapter.getFilter().filter("type1");
                break;
            case 2:
                myDevAdapter.getFilter().filter("type2");
                break;

            default:
                Log.d(debugTag,"error in onTabChanged");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used onfocuschange  or filterable yet but from what you have said sounds like you will need to use them together.

Another possible approach would be to setup an onclicklistener to filter for you. Having a little trouble picturing this. If I have the right idea. You will display ~100 items. Then click a tab and ~50 will show. Then click the other tab, the other ~50 show. click the last tab and all show again?

Comment: Yes, it's that more or less. I have already do that. Inside my activity I used a listener OnTabChange and according the current tab (tabHost.getCurrentTab()) I choose the string wich I want to pass to the filter, like myAdapter.getFilter().filter("String"). Inside my custom adapter, I override the getFilter method and I have implemented a class which extends Filter.